# How to reduce size of install folder which is created by Qt in windows

Tags: windows, qt

I build a code in Qt 5.9 for windows platform.
But the library size is very big (approx 660 MB after `windeployqt`).

How can I reduce the size of the libraries or remove the unused ones?

Comment: Could you please share more info about your project. Also in this case the content of the folder might be interesting as well.

Comment: Is this the size of your folder or the installer created by the Qt Installation Framework? And, what is your build mode -- debug or release?

Comment: Build mode is debug

Answer (score 0):

Since you are building in debug mode, the application contains a lot of additional symbols, which are useful for debugging. Furthermore, the application is linked against the debug version of the required libraries, which also contain debug symbols.

To reduce the size, you have to compile in `Release` or `MinSizeRel` mode. This will reduce the size tremendously. You then need to run `windeployqt` with `--release` flag.

Furthermore, carefully review the files that `windeployqt` copied over. You may not need all of them. I have a little GUI tool, for which I could delete the following files and folders without side effects:

- bearer/
- iconengines/
- imageformats/
- translations/
- D3Dcompiler_47.dll
- libEGL.dll
- libGLESV2.dll
- opengl32sw.dll
- Qt5Svg.dll

With all the measures above, I was able reduce the size of a little application from 684 MB down to 23 MB.